# Powershell script won't stop when process is kill

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I have a script that will keep a minimized/inactive window awake (due to this application that has an 'inactive logout' after 10 minutes.
It will keep the application awake if X process is open. Problem is, if i close X application, the script will still keep it awake. When X is closed, the script must stop. Thanks on beforehand

```
#Application that wants to be awake if X is running
$Proc = Get-process notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Application X that is keeping the process above^ awake
$Proccheck = Get-Process -Name Outlook -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


if ($Proccheck -eq $null) {
  Write-host "Exit script"
  Exit
}
else {
  Write-host "Keep Alive"
  while ($true) {
    if ($Proccheck) {
      if ($proc) {
        # Both applications are running, Keep awake, sleep in 9 minutes before inactive logout  
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 540
        #Activate application to prevent logout
        Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
        [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($Proc.id)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can debug the conditions by displaying the values ... It should show you how to properly code the stop conditions.

Comment: $Proc & $Proccheck defined outside the loop. The conditions of the loop never change so the loop will be infinite. The script completion condition is outside the loop.